# Paypal integration, query

Tags: php, paypal

I have a question.

I'm using this Paypal code: http://www.saaraan.com/2012/07/paypal-expresscheckout-with-php
I would like to have a premium function on my website, where an user can buy something and the premium featuren should directly be active on his account. How can I enable this? Where should I put the Query to update his account? I mean, what if the paymentstatus is pending, then I don't have the money. Does he have the possibility to cancel the order?

Or should I add the query after the GetTransactionDetails. Or is there the possibility that the order is complete, but the query will not be excuted?

Thanks!

Comment: Your description is unclear. What exactly is the "premium" feature, and how will it work? How will it affect the order, price, etc.?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. With a premium function I mean that an account will be updated in the database to an premium status. In fact It's just an updated record, but only when the transaction is completely done (no pending, etc, ....)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for your problem would be to create an IPN listener that would receive the transaction details and, if you code it properly, update your user's account accordingly.  You could have it programmed to only update the account if the IPN shows that the paymentstatus is complete, if you want to.  I have an IPN listener that has about 8 different scenarios depending on the transaction type and payment status.

Do a little research on IPN listeners and you'll see that you can really use them to handle a lot of the tedious details for you.  Paypal's developer site has IPN listener code examples that can help get you started.

Hope this helps.